# asp.net looping through dynamic control in a table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a table which contains questions and a bunch of dynamically created radio button lists, i m trying to write code which will loop through each one of the radio button list and get the  value of the selected question value and corresponding question id . i have the following code which returns the selected radio button list value.how i will get questions ids as well as their selected value?

```
For Each ctrl As Control In form1.Controls
   If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButtonList Then
      Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList)
      For i As Integer = 0 To rbl.Items.Count - 1
         If rbl.Items(i).Selected Then
            Dim value As String = rbl.SelectedValue
         End If
       Next
    End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the radio buttons you should put them into a dictionary (make sure to do so in the `Init` phase). The `String` key is assumed to hold the question id:

```
Dim radios As New Dictionary(Of String, RadioButtonList)
Dim table As DataTable

Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    table = ...
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList
        ' add radio buttons to rbl
        radios.Add(row("id").ToString, rbl)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then in the event handler for retrieving the answers you can easily access them:

```
Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim value As String = GetAnswer(row("id").ToString)
        ' do something with the answer ...
    Next
End Sub

Function GetAnswer(id As String) As String
    For Each item In radios(id)
        If item.Selected Then Return item.SelectedValue
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: where is GetMyQuestions() function. what you have done in that function?

Comment: Well, your questions need to come from somewhere. I just assumed you load them from a given function. Show more of your code than we can easier tell what you'll need to do.

Comment: This code generate dynamic question ids....

Dim lblQuestion As New Label....
 lblQuestion.Text = row("Question").ToString.....
 radioQuestion.ID = "Question_" & row("Id").ToString.....

Comment: Where does `row` come from?

Comment: row("id") is name of primary key column